# Solr unload did not unload Spellcheckcomponent

Tags: solr

i configured IndexBasedSpellchecker in Solr. Problem is after unloading the Core with delete = true the spellccheck index still exists and is still in use. If i stop jetty than i can delete the directory. Any Advices?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming when you state "after unloading the Core with delete = true" that you are referring to the [CoreAdmin - UNLOAD](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#UNLOAD) command. You might try deleting all of the items from the index in that core by referring to ["delete" documents by ID and by query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#A.22delete.22_documents_by_ID_and_by_Query) for an example. I am guessing that if you remove all of the items from the core index prior to unload and delete that the spellcheck index may also be removed.

Answer (score 0):

we wrote a patch for solr 3.6 which closes the spell checker index after unload:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3586

Comment: Not sure this is really an answer.